# SQL SELECT Values from column in one table to a column in another table in order (one by one)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: one with Customers and one with PromoCodes. I need to assign promocodes to Customers (1 code to 1 Customer), taking Promocodes in order and assigning to Customers, one by one.

| CustomerID | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| 123455 | John |
| 123456 | Mary |
| 123457 | Jane |
| 123458 | Bob |

| PromoCode |
| --- |
| ABC12345 |
| YTR23GBS |
| YGNCK453 |
| 12GHRS7G |

And this is the outcome I would need:

| CustomerID | FirstName | PromoCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123455 | John | ABC12345 |
| 123456 | Mary | YTR23GBS |
| 123457 | Jane | YGNCK453 |
| 123458 | Bob | 12GHRS7G |

Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your RDBMS supports *window functions* you can assign a surrogate key to each set using either derived tables or CTEs and use it to join:

```
select CustomerId, Firstname, PromoCode
from (
  select *, Row_Number() over(order by customerId) seq 
  from Customers
) c join (
  select *, Row_Number() over(order by promocode) seq 
  from PromoCodes
) p on c.seq = p.seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine in which order you want the customers and promocodes. Then you can use ROW_NUMBER to assign an Id corresponding to the order. You can then combine the two tables using an inner join.

```
WITH OrderedCustomers AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId) AS [Order#]
FROM Customers
), OrderedPromoCodes AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Promocode) AS [Order#]
FROM Promocodes
)
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedCustomers
INNER JOIN OrderdPromoCodes b
ON a.[Order#] = b.[Order#]
```